# Copy all files and folders except few in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if I can use `FileUtils.cp_r` method to copy all the files and directories from source to target except `.tar` files.
Can someone give me an example for better understanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sure but you'd have to implement some kind of filter first like this:

```
[8] pry(main)> Dir.glob("**/*")
=> ["bin", "CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md", "Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "hello.tar", "lib", "LICENSE.txt", "mygem.gemspec", "Rakefile", "README.md", "spec"]
```

That gave us all the files in that directory and subsequent directories(thanks ndn for that tip), now let's filter out that `hello.tar`:

```
files = Dir.glob("**/*").reject { |file| file.end_with?(".tar") }
```

Now we can pass an array into [`FilteUtils::cp_r`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r)

```
FileUtils.cp_r(files, destination)
```

Comment: using this create doublons:  cp_r will copy all files "flat" in the target directory, and then do a recursive copy for directory listed in files list. So if a file as a path dir/ex.txt it will appear twice in destination: 1) ./ex.txt, 2) ./dir/ex.txt